# Make a second get request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code works, and I get the JSON below returned. What I'm interested in is the `cars_url`. How can I get the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) *(and what is the best way)* then make a secondary get request?

**JSON**

```
{
    created: "2013-11-08T18:57:44",
    domain: "www.test.com",
    cars_url: "/api/v1/carlot/4",
    image: null,
    modified: "2013-11-08T18:57:44"
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.factory('CbgenRestangular', function(Restangular) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
    });
});


app.controller("CampaignData" ,
               [
                   '$scope',
                   'Restangular',
                   'CbgenRestangular',
                   function($scope, Restangular, CbgenRestangular){
                       CbgenRestangular.one('api/v1/person', "james").get().then(
                           function(person) {
                               $scope.person = person;
                               console.log(person)
                           }
                       );
                   }
               ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller("CampaignData" , ['$scope', 'Restangular', 'CbgenRestangular', '$http',
    function($scope, Restangular, CbgenRestangular, $http){

        CbgenRestangular.one('api/v1/person', "james").get().then(function(person) {
                $scope.person = person;
                console.log(person);
                var cars = $http({method: 'GET', url:person.cars_url);
                cars.then(function(data){
                     // do success things here
                }, function(data){
                     /do error things here
                });
            }
        );

}]);
```

Nesting the requests can get messy if you have more than one level deep. In that case, you should use $q to control the flow of the requests.

```
app.controller("CampaignData" , ['$scope', 'Restangular', 'CbgenRestangular', '$http', '$q',
    function($scope, Restangular, CbgenRestangular, $http, $q){
    $scope.person = {cars_url:"your 404 url here"};

    var personcall = CbgenRestangular.one('api/v1/person', "james").get();
    $q.when(personcall.then(
        function(person) {
            $scope.person = person;
            console.log(person);
        }
    ))
    .then(function(){
        var cars = $http({method: 'GET', url:$scope.person.cars_url);
        cars.then(function(data){
             // do success things here
        }, function(data){
             /do error things here
        });
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it any time `$scope.person` changes (which happens in the response from the `person` request), you could set up a `$watch` in your controller.

```
$scope.$watch('person', function(newPerson, oldPerson){
    // Ignore Angular's initial broadcast
    if(!newPerson){
        return false;
    }
    CbgenRestangular.one(newPerson.cars_url).get().then(function(data){
        // Deal with cars data
    });
});
```